# Browser jumps to middle of page with a form on loading

Tags: forms, chrome-browser

Weird behavior happening on Mac only using Chrome and Safari (Haven't tested on FF).

I've got a couple of forms on my site and one of them jumps to the middle of the page on loading. I double checked the page to see if the second parameter of new varienForm() was at false and it was. I don't have any scrolling or any .focus() in my script so I'm kind of clueless of what could be doing this.

Like I wrote earlier, this behavior only happens on Mac.

Anyone had to deal with something similar?

here is the link where it happens:
http://45.79.136.156/index.php/qc_en/partner-in-kind-form/

Thanks!

Comment: Not seeing this happen in Mac Chrome... maybe clear your browser cache

Comment: @AricWatson Did you try reloading the page?

Comment: @AricWatson And wouldn't it be strange that it happens on both chrome and safari, no?

Comment: Yes, I did try reloading the page,  both in Chrome and Firefox - page doesn't jump for me. I do see some javascript that looks like it might do this, but is commented out - could it just be your getting an older cached page somehow that doesn't have that code commented out?

Comment: @AricWatson It happens on OSX Yosemite version 10.10.5. Cache emptied and still happens

Comment: Very odd, I'm also on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Think I found out why, I'll keep you posted

Comment: Thought the problem was magento's cache but after emptying it I still have the same issue, tried on 3 different Mac and only one of them had that problem... I'm trying to compare the browser versions to find a difference but so far everything looks the same. Uber strange..

Comment: Just realized it happens on my android too.

Comment: Hmm do perhaps have a hosts file entry or something that would cause me to see a different site than you?

Comment: No I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I was modifying the wrong custom form template. I was modifying customforms.phtml instead of groupedforms.phtml.

For an odd reason, the form focus was only doing so on mac and android (at least these two, didn't test all).

I feel dumb hahaha